# Markup for an Email Signature or Postal Address in Markdown

Tags: markdown, pagedown

Using pagedown/standard markdown, is there a way to mark up a postal address or email signature block so that it doesn't fold into a single line?

e.g.

```
First Lastname
Some Company
2041 Smile Rd
New York, NY
(999) 999-8888
```

If I leave it as - is like below, it folds to one line. adding an extra line feed wraps each line in paragraph tags.

How can I mark it up so that it displays like above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Markdown Syntax Rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) simply state:

> When you *do* want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.

For illustrative purposes, the following example has all spaces replaced by middle dots (`·`):

```
First·Lastname··
Some·Company··
2041·Smile·Rd··
New·York,·NY··
(999)·999-8888
```

Which results in the following HTML:

```
<p>First Lastname <br />
Some Company <br />
2041 Smile Rd <br />
New York, NY <br />
(999) 999-8888</p>
```

And displays as:

> First Lastname
>   Some Company
>   2041 Smile Rd
>   New York, NY
>   (999) 999-8888

Answer (score 1):

I always (for this) take advantage that most Markdown parsers allow a alimitted subset of html. Including the `<br>` tag

So yours becomes:

```
First Lastname <br>
Some Company <br>
2041 Smile Rd <br>
New York, NY <br>
(999) 999-8888 <br>
```

Displaying as follows:

First Lastname 
Some Company 
2041 Smile Rd 
New York, NY 
(999) 999-8888

I am not aware of a pure Markdown solution,  but I haven't really looked since the HTML way is so easy.

Comment: This will work for sure, but I was hoping there was a more user-friendly solution for the non-technical users